# Tiled shading frustums are reversed

Tags: opengl, frustum

I'm trying to calculate a per tile frustum by getting the screen space coordinates and then using a cross product to get the view frustum planes. However when I check which tiles are affected by a light they are in the opposite direction, as in, they're moving in the opposite direction of the camera as well as being behind it. I've tried changing the cross product order but it doesn't appear to be working either way. Here's the code that generates the frustums and checks if a light intersects it:

```
//Start by getting the corners in screen space
uint minX = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE * gl_WorkGroupID.x;
uint minY = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE * gl_WorkGroupID.y;
uint maxX = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE * (gl_WorkGroupID.x + 1);
uint maxY = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE * (gl_WorkGroupID.y + 1);

//Convert these corners into NDC and then convert them to view space
vec4 tileCorners[4];
tileCorners[0] = unProject(vec4( (float(minX)/SCREEN_WIDTH) * 2.0f - 1.0f, (float(minY)/SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2.0f - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
tileCorners[1] = unProject(vec4( (float(maxX)/SCREEN_WIDTH) * 2.0f - 1.0f, (float(minY)/SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2.0f - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
tileCorners[2] = unProject(vec4( (float(maxX)/SCREEN_WIDTH) * 2.0f - 1.0f, (float(maxY)/SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2.0f - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
tileCorners[3] = unProject(vec4( (float(minX)/SCREEN_WIDTH) * 2.0f - 1.0f, (float(maxY)/SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2.0f - 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

//Create the frustum planes by using the cross product between these points 
frustum[0] = CreatePlane(tileCorners[0], tileCorners[1]); //bot
frustum[1] = CreatePlane(tileCorners[1], tileCorners[2]); //right
frustum[2] = CreatePlane(tileCorners[2], tileCorners[3]); //top
frustum[3] = CreatePlane(tileCorners[3], tileCorners[0]); //left
```

and the functions:

```
vec4 unProject(vec4 v)
{
    v = inverseProjectionMatrix * v;
    v /= v.w;
    return v;
}
vec4 CreatePlane( vec4 b, vec4 c )
{ 
    vec4 normal;
    normal.xyz = normalize(cross( b.xyz, c.xyz ));
    normal.w = 0;
    return normal;
}

float GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( vec4 p, vec4 eqn )
{
    return dot( eqn.xyz, p.xyz );
}
```

And how I check for lights

```
int threadsPerTile = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE*MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE;
for (uint i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LIGHTS; i+= threadsPerTile)
{
    uint il = gl_LocalInvocationIndex + i;


    if (il < NUM_OF_LIGHTS)
    {
        PointLight p = pointLights[il];

        vec4 viewPos = viewMatrix * vec4(p.position.xyz, 1.0f);
        float r = p.radius;

   //     if (viewPos.z + minDepthZ < r && viewPos.z - maxDepthZ < r)
 //       {

        if( ( GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( viewPos, frustum[0] ) < r ) &&
            ( GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( viewPos, frustum[1] ) < r ) &&
            ( GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( viewPos, frustum[2] ) < r ) &&
            ( GetSignedDistanceFromPlane( viewPos, frustum[3] ) < r) )

            {
                uint id = atomicAdd(pointLightCount, 1);
                pointLightIndex[id] = il;
            }
   //     }

    }
}
```

I've commented out the z part just for debugging. The frustums are completely reversed or I'm doing something very wrong, in this picture I'm looking behind me and up, so tiles are affected which are in the complete opposite direction of the scene, and when I move the camera the tiles move in the opposite directions as well

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the frustum was calculated correctly but something about the ARB extensions (which I thought was unrelated) made everything explode. I used

```
#extension GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size : enable
layout( local_size_variable ) in;
```

Which didn't work at all so I just changed it to

```
layout(local_size_x = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, local_size_y = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE) in;
```

And on the CPU:

```
    glDispatchCompute((1280 / 16), (720 / 16), 1);
    //glDispatchComputeGroupSizeARB((1280 / 16), (720 / 16), 1, 16, 16, 1);
```

Which works fine, so I guess there's something about the ARB method that doesn't initialize the amount of work threads properly